# Is there a way to define a getter in dart which takes an index parameter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that it can be done by defining a method in the class. but I want to know if it's possible by defining a getter in dart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getters are not allowed to have any arguments.